# SDK Manager in Android studio not opening when clicked on inside Android studio

Tags: android, windows, sdk, 32-bit, android-developer-api

I am experiencing difficulties when opening the SDK Manager in Android Studio. when i click the sdk manager icon in Android Studio a small window saying starting sdk manager it loads then nothing happens. I have set my environmental Variables and completed the installation process as told and done tons of research but i couldn't get a solution. I just do not know what to do anymore. Can U guys pleases help me? i am using a 32 bit windows 7 laptop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happened to me too after I updated Android Studio from a beta version to 1.0. After trying all sorts of things including uninstalling and reinstalling, what finally worked for me was to modify find_java.bat to be hard-coded for 32-bit as described in this message:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82603

I just modified it like this:

```
rem reg Query "HKLM\Hardware\Description\System\CentralProcessor\0" |^
rem find /i "x86" > NUL && set arch_ext=32|| set arch_ext=64
set arch_ext=32
```

and it was so great to finally see the SDK Manager come up again.

One of the things I had tried before that was following the "Can't Run SDK Manager (Broken find_java.bat)" instructions from this page:
http://tools.android.com/knownissues
but I already had the same versions of find_java.bat, find_java32.exe, and find_java64.exe that are in the find_java.zip file you can download on that page, so it didn't help me. But in case it would help you, there it is.

Comment: This didn't work i edited find_java.bat and when i run android studio and try to open sdk manager it still didn't open i download all of this for nothing.

Comment: Another thing you can do is open up a command window, go to the directory you installed the SDK in, and run "SDK Manager.exe" and see if this gives you any actual error messages you can then search on to find what the problem is. Or as described in "SDK Readme.txt" which should be in your SDK directory, open a command window and run "tools\android.bat update sdk --no-ui" and see what error message(s) you get -- that is what led me to find the solution that worked for me.

Comment: Dude i got it to work finally by downloading the sdk tools by itself and then adjusting the code in android.bat by changing set java_exe=
call lib\find_java.bat
if not defined java_exe goto :EOF  to set java_exe="D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin\java.exe" removing the lines call lib\find_java.bat
if not defined java_exe goto :EOF  it still opens a cmd window when i run sdk manager saying xcopy is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch but sdk manager opens up fine THANKS MAN!!!